# HTML/PHP Form to XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, json

I'm looking to create an .XML file from the inputs of an HTML/PHP form. I know that there are some posts about that, but I couldn't find the solution to my case.

So, I have a form

```
<form action="" method="post" id="sett">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
<input type="text" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Age" />
<input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="Country"/>
<button onclick=send()>Send</button>
</form>
```

If I introduce John as Name, 18 as age and US as Country, I want to get

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sett>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>18</age>
    <country>US</country>
</sett>
```

A way to do it is

```
$xml = "<sett>\n";
$xml .= "\t\t<name>" . $_POST['name'] . "</name>\n"; 
$xml .= "\t\t<age>" . $_POST['age'] . "</age>\n"; 
$xml .= "\t\t<country>" . $_POST['country'] . "</country>\n"; 
$xml .= "</sett>";
$fp = fopen("input.xml","wb");
fwrite($fp,$xml);
fclose($fp);
```

The problem is that I have a large form, not like the one in the example, and it's a bit rought to do it like in the way I just explained. I want to do  it dynamically with JavaScript/jQuery/AJAX/json. I found that I can do it sending the array with json to another script or .PHP and then create the .XML

```
<script>
function send(){
var array= //Array created with the POST/input of the form

$.ajax({
    url: 'createxml.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(array),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data){
    alert('Datos enviados correctamente');
    }
});
}
</script>
```

createxml.php

```
<?php $array = json_encode($_POST['array']); ?>
<?php 
for($i=0;$i < count($array);$i++)  
//Create the .XML from the array
?>
```

I need help with the missing parts (and I don't know if the jQuery/AJAX code is correct): how to create an array from the POST/input of the form, send it to createxml.php, and create the .XML from the array we sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate in PHP as well, creating the tags and values based on the form data

```
$xml = "<sett>\n";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
    $xml .= "<$key>$value</$key>";
}

$xml .= "</sett>";
```

Also, remove the `send()` function and the inline event handler from the form, and just do

```js
$('#sett').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('createxml.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        alert('Datos enviados correctamente');
    });
});
```